# Steps to execute computational queries in AWS Redshift?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

Suppose we have 10,000 records in S3 and Need to compute 2 additional columns in AWS Redshift after replicating the existing data available in S3. For the 2 additional columns, the output of the first column is being used in the computation for column2. This computation has to be done whenever new records arrives at S3 tables (in sync with the S3 data). How can this be achieved?

Comment: set up a dynamic link from redshift to s3 using redshift spectrum. write a query on that table,

Answer (score 0):

Create a staging table in Redshift, where you'll load the data from S3 using `COPY` command, then use [`SELECT INTO`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_SELECT_INTO.html) to compute the required columns and load the data into the main table in Redshift.